# PHP: Unable to load dynamic library intl.so (OSX)

Tags: php, macos, apache, cakephp, icu

I am trying to run a CakePHP app. I've been working for a while in this app and recently I had to install a new dependency (using composer). Once I installed it this error came up and I can't run the app anymore:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
>       '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so, 9): Library not loaded: `/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.56.dylib`
>   Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so  Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0

When I open that folder I can see a different version of that library:

```
libicui18n.57.dylib
```

But the system is looking for

```
libicui18n.56.dylib
```

How can I install the 56 version of that library or upgrade the intl so it uses version 57?

Is that what I need to do?

Thanks!!

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi @JakeN I couldn't fix this. Well, I did, but I basically reinstalled the OS and started from scratch...Not sure if a fix have come up recently.

Comment: I managed it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304068/php-intl-so-fails/38304256#38304256

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question when i upgrade node to v8.x.
After i run `brew upgrade node`,the `icu4c` was updated.
I solve the problem by under command:

`brew unlink php56-intl
brew remove php56-intl
brew install php56-intl`

so, i feel you should reinstall intl extension.

Comment: Thanks @Rambo I will give it a try!