# PHP intl.so fails

Tags: php, mongodb, homebrew

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so, 9):
>   Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.56.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so   Reason:
>   image not found in Unknown on line 0

I recently was trying to install MongoDB for PHP, I used

```
 brew install homebrew/php/php55-mongodb
```

This installed a whole load of other requirements and now intl.so for PHP is broken. I get the above error whenever I run `composer update` and the libs I have that need intl.so now break and say its not present.

I believe this is related to the issue but it offers no solution https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2544

How can I undo this mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more digging I removed, then installed intl using pecl and this seems to have worked. I also removed and then reinstalled icu4c as this is a related package that causes the issue;

```
sudo pecl remove intl
brew unlink icu4c
brew remove icu4c
brew install icu4c
sudo pecl install intl
```

Comment: Worked perfectly after reinstalling icu4c. Thanks!!